# Changing file name from dbf to ods problem?

Tags: filenames, conversion, spreadsheet

I was trying to change the file name from gdf to csv in the folder using

`$for i in *.dbf; do mv $i ${i%.dbf}.ods; done`  script.

The code changed all the gdf to csv, but the content of the new files is diffenet from the orginal gdf file.

Here are the sample files below. The file has two  columns.

1_CopyRow.dbf

```
time,N,19,11    prec,N,13,11
19710101.00000000000    0.02072840000
19710102.00000000000    0.42218300000
19710103.00000000000    0.17756100000
19710104.00000000000    0.33698200000
19710105.00000000000    0.11057700000
19710106.00000000000    0.02841580000
19710107.00000000000    0.00000000000
19710108.00000000000    0.00000000000
19710109.00000000000    0.00000000000
```

the result from above code is 
1_CopyRow.ods

- rma!WtimeFprecF

  1.97101010000e+007  2.07284e-002    1.97101020000e+007  4.22183e-001    1.97101030000e+007  1.77561e-001    1.97101040000e+007  3.36982e-001    1.97101050000e+007  1.10577e-001    1.97101060000e+007

I want the output be file be the same as the input. 
I couldn't figure out how to fix the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: cannot possibly happen from the `mv` command. How are you opening these files?

Comment: They are ArcGIS table outputs. I opened them using excel import

Answer (score 1):

The files *are* the same.  If you open a terminal and type `cat 1_CopyRow.dbf` followed by `cat 1_CopyRow.ods` then you'll notice that they are the same.

What's happening is that Open/Libre Office (I presume you're opening the `.ods` file using this) is formatting the file for display.

```
1.97101010000e+007 = 1.9710101 x 10^7 = 19710101 = 19710101.000000000
```

That is, they are all the same value.

Note that your question is unclear as to whether you're renaming to `.ods` or `.csv`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. They look the same from the terminal. But when I open them with excel, they are different. The dbf is table output form ArcGIS. It has two columns only. When I open the .ods/csv file after changing the name, they are arranged all in one row. I have a couple of these file to join all in one file for my model input. It can ce changed either to .ods or .txt or .csv.

Comment: Ah! I see what you're asking now. A CSV file expects commas between fields (hence the name - Comma Separated Values) but your data doesn't have this.  I believe Excel has an option to import from text files and gives you the option to choose the field delimiter.  If the large space between the columns is a tab, then choose 'tab' when you import.

Comment: @garethTheRed as a side note, I always liked using `diff <file one> <file two> > delta.txt`. `diff` is very useful in situations like this, especially if `num_of_lines >> 10` :-)

Comment: @Simply_Me I did consider `diff` but (on Ubuntu & Fedora at least) it needs the `diffutils` package installed - I assumed `cat` would be on all systems.  Also, if I was wrong, `diff` would have spewed out some scary looking results!